# Flask-security add role to user (MongoEngine)

Tags: python, flask, mongoengine, flask-security

I've built a small api that should be able to add the role to a user:

```
user = user_datastore.find_user(email=flask.request.args.get('email'))
role = user_datastore.find_role(flask.request.args.get('role'))
result = user_datastore.add_role_to_user(user, role)
```

(`role` & `email` are sent through the api). It finds correct user and role objects, the result gives `True` but nothing is added to the user's role list which stays `[]` without any roles.

My setup is similar to/directly based upon the [MongoEngine example](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/quickstart.html)

It must be something really simple, but I cannot seem to find it :/

BR Carst

Comment: Probably `add_role_to_user` do not save object (see https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/datastore.py#L97) and you must call `user.save()`.

Comment: Looks to be a bug in my code. Submit an issue?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Matt W, it seems to be a bug. I've logged an issue in github at:
https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/170

Answer (score -1):

May be I am missing something but you need to commit the changes, right ?

```
user = user_datastore.find_user(email=flask.request.args.get('email'))
role = user_datastore.find_role(flask.request.args.get('role'))
result = user_datastore.add_role_to_user(user, role)

# to save in database, you must commit (assuming 'db' is the object)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: Hi codegeek, that would be true for sqlalchemy, but not when using mongoengine. So in this particular case that's not it (but it might be for other people who come in here with the issue while using a sql db)